# Amazon Product API not return Fulfilled Offer

Tags: price, amazon-product-api

I am using Amazon Product API and invoking ItemLookup service.
I want to extract the best lower price, I am not able to find what is the exact field to read ( I know camelcamelcamel able to use the correct field).

I wonder if someone worked with the service and can share his experience.

There are 3 options:

lowest price by third party but with shipping ( i dont want this result )
lowest price sold by amazon (i dont want this result )
lowest third party fulfilled by amazon **( i want this result )**

I want the lowest price that is super saver or prime.

I dont find any combination in ItemLookup parameters to get this info.
API return the lowest price for amazon or not for amazon that's all.

My current request look parameters is:

```
idType: 'ASIN',
itemId: PCodes,
responseGroup: 'ItemAttributes,Offers,Images,OfferFull',
condition: 'New'
```

I expect to get response with the lowest fulfillment price